# DataGridView cannot display data c#

Tags: c#

I try to display data in the DataGridView in C# but it can't show anything at all. My DataGridView is inside a private static void function.

```
private static void processsub(Event a , Session session)
{ 
   List<String[]> lista = new List<string[]>();
   lista.add(new string[] {text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7 });
   Form1 frm1 = newForm1();
   frm1.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
   DataTable table = ConvertListtoDatTable(lista);
   frm1.dataGridview1.DataSource = table;
}
```

I used the messagebox window to display the " .Row[0].Cell[0].Value.ToString()" and it shows the right value but the DataGridView just didn't display the data.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Is it not frm1.dataGridView1 instead of frm.dataGridView1 ?

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo in here.

Comment: Have you tried setting the AutoGenerateColumns flag _after_ setting the DataSource? Oddly, the [example code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) goes through how to set this flag to false and add columns manually.

Comment: Have you tried to Debug your DataTable namely the "Table" variable if it has Rows to begin with? I know you said you did the Row[0].Cell[0] but just to be sure.

Comment: Edper, yes, I have tired debug my table and it got the right value as well.
Zec, I tried to add column manually but it doesn't work either. Thanks

Comment: @user2644434. My suggestion was to set your datasource _then_ set the AutoGenerateColumns flag. The manually-adding-columns thing was an admittedly irrelevant observation.

Comment: Have you checked the **DefaultCellStyle** `property` of your DataGridView1 if it is the right color? Because it could be that the color of the font is white and the background is white hence you could not see anything? By the way are their multiple rows or at least one row of your DataGridView when shown despite appearing empty?

Comment: Zec, I set the autoGenerateColumns after but it still doesn't work.
I have a 60 sec function looping the processsub function. 
Edper, I check the DefaultCellStyle and the color is alright.
It should have multiple rows

Comment: user2492798, it wont work in the private static void function.  Thanks

Comment: I found it is because of the private static void function. Even I try to pass a string into a textbox. The textbox still doesn't have the new value.  Anyone can help me please.

Comment: In order to make it work, I change my function from "private static void" into "private void".  Could anyone give me a better solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You may not spread rows.My test code is as the following.

```
   private void processsub()
    {
        List<String[]> lista = new List<string[]>();
        lista.Add(new string[] { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7" });
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        DataTable table = ConvertListtoDatTable(lista);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private DataTable ConvertListtoDatTable(List<String[]> lista)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        int columnCount = lista[0].Length;
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++)
        {
            table.Columns.Add();
        }
        foreach (string[] row in lista)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }

    private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processsub();
    }
```

Execute result:
[image]